# measuring average directional intensity of LED?

Tags: measurements, light-emitting-diodes

Although I am poor at physics and math I want to compare two light sources of which I haven’t decided the specific brand yet. I was thinking of florescence bulbs versus LED lamps. So something like [this florescence](http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-19056/Light-Bulbs/Sylvania-Fluorescent-Tubes-96-T-12-Cool-White-Single-Pin?pricode=WY669&gadtype=pla&id=S-19056Q2&gclid=CjwKEAjwho2xBRD0mpzUvsya6SgSJAAkRepSVCB1pkSbElyhW2AQKBjTEsmPSTCwBANGdqSG47GuyhoC5YDw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) versus something like [this LED](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/351189122067?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82) for light intensity.

After googling I found this source: https://www.labsphere.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/The-Radiometry-of-Light-Emitting-Diodes-LEDs.pdf

It was very dense for me, but I  managed to make some sense out of it. This passage helped me understand that for LED's I should be measuring the average directional intensity, copy pastaed below, bold emphasis is mine.

> As discussed in the previous section, it is very difficult to measure
>   the "true" intensity of an LED and in the real world **it has become
>   common practice to measure an "average" directional intensity.** In
>   attempt to offer an agreed upon procedure for measuring "average"
>   intensity within the industry, CIE Committee TC 2-34 has published CIE
>   127, which develops the concept of averaged LED intensity. This
>   concept no longer corresponds to the physically precise definition of
>   luminous intensity, but relates more to the measurement of flux for a
>   fixed geometry.

Therefore knowing this, how would I acutally go about this for a large grow lamp like the one stated above?

The diagram in the .pdf showed a set up, posted below:

[image]

So would I set up the LED lamps in that type of orientation? **And then how would I actually take the measurement?** Would I  place a device at the position labelled detector, and what kind? A spectroradiometer?

**ASIDE**( I was not sure if this was on topic, but since I also wanted to measure the intensity of the florescent bulb to compare, would I use the same methods and equipment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a typical LED is that the light distribution tends to be quite "lumpy" - because the light emitted from the actual semiconductor is collimated with a lens, you create a poor image of the source with all its variations in intensity. If you picked a random point, you might be measuring an intensity that is not representative of the overall luminous power of the LED.

The setup suggested takes care of that. If you just want to compare two devices (LED with fluorescent lamp) and you don't have a good device for measuring the intensity over a large area, then I would suggest a setup in which you have a translucent screen (ground glass or tracing paper, for example) of sufficient size covering an enclosed cavity (for example a large cardboard box). A photodiode (or other photo sensor) at a fixed position inside this cavity will be illuminated (albeit weakly) with a "average" intensity from the light source.

You can now compare the intensity of your different light sources by using an identical setup. And if you want to calibrate your setup (estimate the effect of your "averaging" on the absolute measurement) you can measure the intensity for a uniformly distributed source (like the fluorescent tube) and repeat it with the "naked" photo sensor (at the location of the scattering screen).

EDIT: diagram to explain the above a little more clearly:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I seem to be missing the purpose of the screen. Could you some how diagram this out in ms paint or give me an visual aid? Thank you.

Comment: @RoSiv - I added a diagram

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused about some things still, I do not understand the function of the screen is it to make the light wave you squiggled uniform somehow, and then so it hits the sensor better? It would be good to have some sources to read upon that are digestible for a layman if possible. I feel like the one I picked above was a bit above me.

Comment: The screen is known as a _diffuser_ - any point on the screen transmits the light that hits it diffusely in all directions, so it acts to average the light intensity. The box really needs to be white on the inside for the best averaging effect.

Comment: If the box was not white, would it drastically throw off my results? And is there data on what materials are best for diffusing? I tried to google but did not find anything.

Comment: No making the box non white would affect the results only slightly - intense peaks near the edge of the diffuser would be VERY slightly less important in the final result. You can test the effect by shining a point source (laser pointer) at different parts of the diffuser and recording the signal at the detector. Ground glass is a good diffuser but you could just use tracing paper - it will absorb some of the light but if you are just interested in a comparison it should not be too bad.